# Trouble getting device token into global variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I am trying to get the device token and then put that device token into a global variable (or access it from another view). The code in my AppDelgate is as follows:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSMutableData*)deviceToken
{
    DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];


    obj.userDevice = deviceToken;

      NSLog(@"%@",obj.userDevice);


}
```

This displays the token. But when I try to access it through the global variable in another view, it displays "null". The code for that is as follows:

```
 DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];


NSLog(@"%@",obj.userDevice);
```

Any ideas? Or another solution? I just want to access the token from another view so I'm open to other suggestions.

EDIT: DataClass

```
   static DataClass *instance =nil;
    +(DataClass *)getInstance

{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(instance==nil)
        {

            instance= [DataClass new];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: I assume that DataClass is set up as a singleton.  Can you add the code for the `getInstance` method?

Comment: Edited with the DataClass.h :)

Comment: Is that the full DataClass.h?  Where is the userDevice property declared?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the userDevice has been set in DataClass before the other view controller accesses it?  Also, a singleton may be a bit of an overkill - you could just use a simple `@property` on your appDelegate, and you can use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` to get a reference to your appDelegate where required

Comment: Found a different way round it. I've found an answer. It involves saving the token to the user defaults. Thank you for your help.

Comment: why do you need it to be global?